# Jquery Autocomplete "almost" working but list doesn't populate completely

Tags: php, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to use autocomplete in jquery, and it works with the demo data, but I haven't been able to make it work with my own data source. I'm trying to write a mailer where the user just enters a few letters of a person's name, and the contacts database helps autocomplete so that the corresponding emails show up in the "To" field.

I've included the following files:

```
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

My jQuery code in document.load is below:

```
   $(function() {
    function log( message ) {
        $('#to').append(message);
        console.log(message);
    }

   $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
     log( ui.item? ui.item.email : "NO" );
        }
    }); 
});
```

And my HTML is:

```
<div class='ui-widget'><input type='text' class='medium' id='search' /></div> <br />
To:<br />
<div class='ui-widget'> <textarea type='text' style='width:80%; height:24px;' id='to' class='ui-widget-content'></textarea></div>
```

The result of search.php is fine as far as json is considered, here's a sample of the output when the letters "Ahmed" are pressed:

```
[{"email":"saddi@yahoo.com","name":"Ahmed Qasim"},{"email":"aaaab@alangari.com.sa","name":"Ahmed Abbas"},{"email":"mokhlef@yahoo.com","name":"Ahmed Sahdi"}]
```

I know I'm getting this response from search.php because I check Firebug and see it, but it doesn't show up below the search input field... Instead, what does show up is just a stump of a list... as in the image below.

[image]

But this exact same thing worked as expected when I used the demo code here: [demo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) Why doesn't the list show up properly? Is there a limit on how much data can be displayed? I've pasted only 3 entries from the JSON output I got, but there were tens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are returning from server contains `email` and `name` fields, jquery ui needs an `value` and `label` field.

```
[{"label":"Ahmed Abbas", value: "Ahmed Abbas"}]
```

`label` is what you see on autocomplete list, and `value` is the value you will get when you select an item.

Answer (score 3):

I think keune has the correct diagnosis. If you don't want to change the output of search.php, you could do something like this:

```
            $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "search.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { searchText: myQuery, maxResults: 10 },
                        success: function(data) {
                            var mappedData = $.map(data,
                                function(item) {
                                    return {
                                        label: item.name,
                                        value: item.email,
                                        id: item.email
                                    };
                                });

                            response(mappedData);
                            }
                        });
                }, ....
```

Comment: We should be able to vote a change in accepted answer. This is more relevant to the OP's issue (and mine) when an existing data feed can't be altered to match some UI widget's default setup.